# Reuse the RecyclerView adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have very small question here, in my recycle view adapter class i'm using `List<FeaturedTags>` and its working fine.

Now we have newly introduced class called '`FeaturedLangTags`, the only difference between `FeaturedTags` & `FeaturedLangTags`is just an addition of `Lang` field. But we are not using this Lang field anyway to show on screen.

The output of the recycle view looks exactly similar to existing `FeaturedTags` adapter. Here i want to know how i can re-use the existing adapter class to display `List<FeaturedLangTags>` items?

One simple way is to duplicate the existing adapter and pass the `FeaturedLangTags`list, but here so much of code is getting duplicated. I would like to know how i can tweek the existing class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Adapter of generic `List<T>` which can be used in both condition.

```
public abstract class GenericAdapter<T> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<T> items;

    public abstract RecyclerView.ViewHolder setViewHolder(ViewGroup parent);

    public abstract void onBindData(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, T val);

    public GenericAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<T> items){
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = setViewHolder(parent);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        onBindData(holder,items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void addItems( ArrayList<T> savedCardItemz){
        items = savedCardItemz;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public T getItem(int position){
        return items.get(position);
    }
}


adapter = new GenericAdapter<DataModel>(context,modelList) {
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder setViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
            final View view =            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_holder, parent, false);
            ItemViewHolder viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(context, view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindData(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder1, DataModel val) {
                DataModel userModel = val;

                ItemViewHolder holder = (ItemViewHolder)holder1;
                holder.name.setText(userModel.getName());
                holder.fatherName.setText(userModel.getFatherName());
        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a common interface or superclass to `FeaturedTags` and `FeaturedLangTags`, then use the same adapter.

Or use a more generic approach to your adapter like [AdapterDelegates](https://github.com/sockeqwe/AdapterDelegates).

Answer (score 0):

You can create two different constructors for the adapter and achieve it.

Comment: But, how will i fetch the data?. i.e onBindViewHolder method?

Answer (score 0):

You can have both the classes implement one common interface say CommonInterface

Make your list of type

```
YourList<CommonInterface>
```

In your adapter, override the

```
getItemViewType
```

Method. Here use the instance of operator to check what type of class it is and return a view type integer. Say for without lang, it will be an integer 0 and with it, 1

Now in your onCreateViewHolder, you get passed the viewType as the second parameter. Using that inflate your layout as your choice for the view.

In your onBindViewHolder, you can check

```
getItemViewType
```

On the holder passed in the parameter and cast your interface explicitly to the object you want. Then use it as usual.

Reference for this multiple view types is 
[Recycler view multiple view types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ConcatAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter) of RecyclerView to concatenate your adapters and reuse them.

```java
    MyAdapter adapter1 = ...;
    AnotherAdapter adapter2 = ...;
    ConcatAdapter concatenated = new ConcatAdapter(adapter1, adapter2);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(concatenated);
```

"Favor composition over inheritance"